# How to input password to sudo using java Runtime?

Tags: java, passwords, sudo

I need to execute the given commands as root and sudo user using Java. However, I am not sure about the method that I can use to pass the password. Is there  a way by which I can pass the password to the terminal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just drop sodu all together and create a shell script suid root and run that instead.

```
chmod +s myscript && chown root myscript && chgrp root myscript
```

whenever that script is called it will be run as root.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure sudo to allow a specific command to run without a password. This doesn't require you to know the password.

Having the root password in the program which has to be clear text at some stage is actually less secure IMHO.

Comment: This could be useful, but in my case, I will not always know beforehand the script that is going to be executed through the sudo, hence cannot set the sudoers file each time/r configure sudo for each script to be run. I am assuming that we make that setting in sudoers file, right?

Comment: You can make the user able to run anything, but that sounds dangerous all round.  This allows a compromised system to run anything, with or without needing a password, its a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Normally sudo reads the password by operating directly on the terminal. You should use `sudo -S` here. With this option, it will try to read the password from standard input and then you can send it via the `OutputStream` you get from the `Process` created by `Runtime.exec()` when you run your command.

Comment: It does, however, I need to disable the requiretty option in sudoers file for it.

Answer (score 1):

Getting from one machine to the other using ssh or scp can be done if you configure password-less ssh.  This is one method that is used for clusters of machines that need to work together and are controlled by a head node.  For example hadoop uses this method.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you create a script on the terminal and call it from Java(using Runtime.exec)

Answer (score 0):

As guys already mentioned you can use `sudo` only if your current use is configured at the system as one that can run `sudo`. Otherwise (in general case) you have to type password.

You have to type password if you want to run commands on remote computers as well using `ssh` or copy files remotely using `scp`.

Some commands can accept password as a parameter of command line. For example `mysql` utility can accept password after switch `-p`. Some other commands are more strict: they do not exept password in command line and even do not allow you to supply password via redirecting of stdin of the process. Examples are `ssh` and `scp`.

The only way to be sure that you can always programmatically run any command that requires typing the password is to emulate the terminal. This is what utility `expect` does. Take a look on its man page: http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect

I used `expect` in past. it is script driven utility that allows simulating user's actions exactly as human user is doing when he is working with terminal. We ran the expect script from java as regular external process using `ProcessBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use ProcessBuilder to run tcpdump.  Here is how I did it:

visudo
myuser ALL= NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/tcpdump

Then my command from Java was, which was run from myuser:
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/tcpdump -i eth0 port 8561 ...