# How to unmount a Linux folder from Java

Tags: java, linux, shell

I tried:

```
final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("umount", "foldername");
final Process p = pb.start();
```

Throws

> umount: /home/user/foldername is not in the fstab (and you are not
>   root)

I tried

```
final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("sudo","umount", "foldername");
final Process p = pb.start();
```

Throws

> sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo

I got the root password, but can't provide it to the `ProcessBuilder`. Also I cannot edit `fstab` (or whatever is needed to be edited), because it is remote virutal machine started on a remote server from saved OS image.

I just want to run the command as root.

Comment: Do these commands work when run directly from terminal?

Comment: First command prints exactly the same if I'm not root(if I'm root, it unmounts the folder successfully). Second command prompts for password.

Comment: you could allow the user running your java program to unmount without entering a password. Take a look at the file /etc/sudoers (editable with command "visudo") for a few examples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to input password to sudo using java Runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716609/how-to-input-password-to-sudo-using-java-runtime)

Comment: This answer may be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716609/how-to-input-password-to-sudo-using-java-runtime

Comment: To edit /etc/sudoers I must previously entered with the root account. But since I only can do it manually, it is not very useful. I need root privileges in my java process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. Make the controlling terminal available for `sudo` so that the user can type the password there.

   ```
   pb = new ProcessBuilder("sh", "-c", "sudo umount foldername </dev/tty");
   Process p = pb.start();
   p.waitFor();
   ```
2. Execute the program with `gksudo` rather than `sudo`. Systems that use GTK+ often come with the `gksu` package as a graphical interface for `su` and `sudo`.

   ```
   pb = new ProcessBuilder("gksudo","umount", "foldername");
   ```
3. Open a terminal emulator window for `sudo`:

   ```
   pb = new ProcessBuilder("xterm","-e","sudo","umount","foldername");
   ```