# how to use sudo in ammonite shell"

Tags: scala, ammonite

One thing which sucks about Scala REPL is that there is no straight forward way of loading maven/sbt dependencies.

I found ammonite shell which has a convenient thing like `load.ivy` which is pretty sweet. it also has a decent wrapper over file system.

However I didn't find a way to do a sudo. So for example if I am looping over files in a directory and I don't have permission on a folder the command fails

```
ls.rec! cwd | (x => x.size -> x.last) sortBy (-_._1) take 3
```

Error

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /Users/foo/Library/Saved Application State/com.bitrock.appinstaller.savedState
  sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
  sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
  sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
  sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:407)
  java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:457)
```

does anyone know how to do a sudo in the ammonite shell?

Comment: shouldn't your question title be like "how to use sudo in ammonite shell"?

Comment: I edited the title. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to provide a password for sudo from JVM process calls:

- [How to execute bash command with sudo privileges in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708087/how-to-execute-bash-command-with-sudo-privileges-in-java)
- [How to run sudo command without password from java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732526/how-to-run-sudo-command-without-password-from-java-program)
- [Execute a linux shell command with "sudo" using java, without entering the required password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168755/execute-a-linux-shell-command-with-sudo-using-java-without-entering-the-requi)
- [How to input password to sudo using java Runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716609/how-to-input-password-to-sudo-using-java-runtime)

Personally, what I found the most straight forward solution is to set the `SUDO_ASKSPASS` environment variable. Something like

```
val sudo = "sudo"
val askPass = "/usr/bin/ssh-askpass"
val procBuilder = Process(List(sudo, "-A", ???), None, "SUDO_ASKPASS" -> askPass)
val res = procBuilder.!
```